# Shrinking space between cards in hand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the spread of the cards in the hand of a player restricted to the holder's width, in this case 45em(10px font). I've tried achieving this by giving negative values to margin-right and margin-left. It didn't work quite well for me seeing how I depend on a "center" card towards which I move cards.

Here is the code I'm trying.

```
Template.playerHand.rendered = () ->
    hand = this.findAll '.card'
    size = this.cards().count()
    center = Math.ceil (size / 2)
    margin = size / -2
    if size > 5
        $(hand).each (el) ->

            if (el+1) < center
                $(this).css "margin-right", "#{margin}em"

            if (el+1) > center
                $(this).css "margin-left", "#{margin}em"
    else
        $(hand).each () ->
            $(this).css 
                "margin-left": 0
                "margin-right": 0
```

Is there any Math operation for this?

Comment: Have you tried using absolute positioning of the cards?

Comment: @SethMcClaine Same thing with the absolute positioning.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: So anyone got an idea how to make this work? 
it works now, but once the cards are more than 8, issues start to appear.